# Incomplete beta function with negative domain

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals, special-functions, hypergeometric-function

I have the following integral and I try to solve this integral by incomplete beta function;

$$\int_{0}^{-d}y^{a}\left(1-y\right)^{-\alpha}dy=\frac{\left(-d\right)^{a+1}}{a+1}{}_{2}F_{1}\left(a+1,2-\alpha;a+2;-d\right)$$

My doubt is the negative value of upper bound.

I guess that even from the beginning, the result of an integral will not change if I reverse the bounds by putting a negative sign but in this but in this case,

I can not figure out how to write the hypergeometric function as the integral would be

$$-\int_{-d}^{0}y^{a}\left(1-y\right)^{-\alpha}dy$$

How should I proceed in this case ?

Comment: Are you certain that $d>0$? And if it's indeed the case, then what is your problem? You have your answer in terms of Hypergeometric function, it works fine with negative argument